# Heroku Django App + Azure PostgreSQL DB - slow connections

Tags: django, postgresql, azure, heroku

I have an app hosted on heroku and moved my DB to azure recently, because of the way SSL is handled by heroku postgres.

Even though my new Azure Postgres is plenty more potent than the former heroku:postgres equivalent, I am encountering severe slow downs.

I have setup PGBouncer to use connection pooling but I am still not seeing the the performance improve.

Any clues as to what I could try?

Answer (score 1):

You're running into network latency issues between Heroku (which runs at AWS) and Azure.  All your traffic has to go across the public internet between the two data centers.

Comment: Ist there any way to avoid this or decrease the latency?

Comment: Running Postgres at AWS would be my first thought.  You can grab your own VM and do it  yourself, or there are other providers that will offer it as a managed service.